# Shared memory using shmget()

Tags: linux, shared-memory

According to my understanding about shared memory is that it is a memory segment that is shared between two or more processes.  Shared memory can be  implemented using `shmget()` . However , since any process cant access a memory segment that is not included in its address space , we need to attach this shared memory to the adress space of the processes. According to my understanding of the word attach , attach means that we take this created memory segment and includes it in the address space of the two processes , however , when I print the starting address of this shared memory ( which is the return value of the function `shmat()` ) I see that the address is different in every process. This has confused me , how if the shared memory is a single "container " in the memory that is shared between two processes and then it has two different starting addresses ? Is this means that the content of the shared memory in the first processes is copied into a new memory segment in the other process ?

Comment: You need to read up a little on process address space (a quick look at Wikipedia indicates this _might_ be it - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space ). Basically, each process has its own memory map.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Is this means that the concept of shared memory is that two or more processes shares the same virtual address space that are actually mapped to different physical address space of each process ? In other words , we cant have two or more processes have the same physical address space ?

Answer (score 1):

The address you get back from `shmat()` is a virtual address, as is any address which can be used directly as a pointer. Virtual addresses are indirect: they effectively point into address translation tables ([page tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table)) which tell the CPU whether the corresponding memory is actually mapped, and where to find it in physical memory. On most Unix-style multi-tasking systems where processes are protected from each other, each process gets its own virtual address space.

Shared memory is a single set of physical pages which are mapped into multiple processes’ virtual address spaces. Since each process is liable to use its virtual address space differently, the same shared memory is liable to end up at different virtual addresses inside each process sharing it. Otherwise, a process with something already allocated at the required address wouldn’t be able to access a given piece of shared memory.

(There are systems where the virtual address space is the same across processes; see [single address-space operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_address_space_operating_system) for details.)